# How can I add implicit animation for the 'position' property of a CALayer?

Tags: ios, uikit, core-animation

**Note: This is for iOS, not OS X, so implicit animations aren't automatically set up.

I am trying to add implicit animation to a CALayer for the position property.

My (incorrect) code is this:

```
NSMutableDictionary * actions = [self.view.layer.actions mutableCopy ] ;
if ( !actions ) { actions = [ NSMutableDictionary dictionary ] ; }

CABasicAnimation * anim = [ CABasicAnimation animationForKeyPath:@"position" ] ;

[ actions setValue:anim forKey:@"position" ] ;
self.view.layer.actions = actions ;
```

My question is, what sort of animation (the **anim** property, above) i.e. `CABasicAnimation`, `CATransition` should I use for this scenario and how should I configure it?

Grazie

Answer (score 1):

Implicit animations, are triggered by just setting the position property (i.e `self.view.layer.position = <new position>;`) and Quartz will take care of the rest using your current [CATransaction](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CATransaction_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) setting.

If you want to use explicit animation (which you seem to be trying to do), I would use CABasicAnimation and do something like this.

```
    self.view.layer.position = <new position>;
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    animation.duration = <duration>;
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
    animation.fromValue = <current position>;
    animation.toValue = <new position>;
    [line addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
```

Comment: I should have been more specific--what you say is true on OS X, but on iOS implicit animations aren't set up automatically.. as far as I know.

Comment: Last time I did this, (iOS 4.x) they were set up automatically if I remember correctly. Otherwise, you may need to wrap the changes in `[CATransaction begin]` and `[CATransaction commit]`

Comment: If this were true wouldn't doing `layer.position = p` cause position to animate? I only see an abrupt transition.